# Internal page navigation using Angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a full working ASP.Net Zero application navigation working. Now I created an internal page I want to navigate, something like this:

[image]

With the following structure:

[image]

Content of `test.component.html`:

```
<div [@routerTransition]>
<div class="m-content">
    <div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile tests">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="m-portlet__head">
                    <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
                        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
                            <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">Spellings</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There I defined the `<router-outlet>` to navigate using the "Navigation Area" of the pic.

I created a custom routing navigation defined in `spelling-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test-list/test.component';
import { QuestionComponent } from './questions/questions.component';
import { TestContainerComponent } from './test-list/test-container/test-container.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: TestComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: 'test-container', component: TestContainerComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Tenant.Tests' } },
                    { path: 'questions/:testId', component: QuestionComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Tenant.Tests' } }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class SpellingRoutingModule { }
```

This works to load the main `test.component.html`, but can't fill the `<router-outlet>` inside it to navigate to some inner Components.

Please, how to fill the `<router-outlet>` object of `test.component.html` with a default one?

See the `src` folder content here:

[Dropbox link to src folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6zcleld1i2nmq26/AAAdZhE4yXkK0kj8pdDmrnt7a?dl=0)

Comment: In your router, you have grouped your routes with an empty one `''`, but you don't put a default route in the children. Create a `''` route in the children, that either redirects, or displays a component.

Comment: If I do so, I loose the `main-routing.module` navigation. I need to create a navigation that depends on the one created for the main applicaiton...

Comment: Frmo your code, that's not true : nowhere in the child routing there is a main route.

Comment: @Sonhja can you upload the code of main routing

Comment: I'm going to upload the src code for the app. Give me a while so it uploads in a public place...

Comment: I uploaded the src folder. I'm not sure where to create my internal routing ts file, and how to do so...